# forceclient async call never received

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, nsubstitute

I'm unit testing one of my async methods but it turns out to be a bit tricky.
In my code I execute two actions witch I try to verify with NSubstitute like so

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GivenDebatchingHandler_WhenCommandReceived_EventIsPublishedAndStatusUpdated()
{
    // arrange
    var forceClient = Substitute.For<IForceClient>();
    forceClient.UpdateAsync(EntityNames.EventStore, Arg.Any<string>(), Arg.Any<ExpandoObject>()).Returns(info => Task.FromResult(new SuccessResponse { Success = true }));
    var messageHandlerContext = Substitute.For<IMessageHandlerContext>();
    var handler = new DebatchingHandler(forceClient);
    var @event = new KlantManagementEnvelopeCreatedEvent { Header = new Header { MessageId = "UnitTest" } };
    var cmd = new PublishMultipleKlantManagementEnvelopeCreatedEventsCommand { EventsLargePayload = new List<KlantManagementEnvelopeCreatedEvent>(new[] { @event }) };

    // act
    await handler.Handle(cmd, messageHandlerContext).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // assert
    await messageHandlerContext.Received().Publish(@event, Arg.Any<PublishOptions>()).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await forceClient.Received().UpdateAsync(EntityNames.EventStore, "UnitTest", Arg.Any<ExpandoObject>()).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

The publish is received, but the `UpdateAsync` is not. This is the code under test:

```
public async Task Handle(PublishMultipleKlantManagementEnvelopeCreatedEventsCommand message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
{        
    await Task.WhenAll(message.EventsLargePayload.Select(@event => this.ProcessEvent(@event, context))).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public async Task ProcessEvent(KlantManagementEnvelopeCreatedEvent envelopeCreatedEvent, IMessageHandlerContext context)
{
    await context.Publish(envelopeCreatedEvent).ConfigureAwait(false);

    var eventStoreRecord = new EventStore__c { Status__c = EventStoreStatus.Published.ToName() };
    await this.forceClient.UpdateAsync(EntityNames.EventStore, envelopeCreatedEvent.Header.MessageId, eventStoreRecord).ConfigureAwait(false);        
}
```

Why is the `UpdateAsync` call never received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test has `Arg.Any<ExpandoObject>()` in the `UpdateAsync` assert.

Unless `EventStore__c` in the method under test derives from `ExpandoObject` then I don't think that assertion would match.

Try using

```
await forceClient.Received()
      .UpdateAsync(EntityNames.EventStore, "UnitTest", Arg.Any<EventStore__c>())
      .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the problem